# Unable to send data using firebase data on app first time launch

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hey I am trying to send firebase data when the app launches for the first time. I am trying to send the data(qid) from the splash activity to all the other activities.

This is the function I am calling in the splash activity

```
  public void setImageName() {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            long timeStampLong = (long) dataSnapshot.child("time").child("timestamp").getValue();
            SimpleDateFormat questiondateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            String currentDate = questiondateFormat.format(new Date(timeStampLong));
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
            SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

            Date d = null, d1 = null;
            try {
                d1 = sdf1.parse(currentDate);
                d = sdf.parse(currentDate + " " + "08:00:00 PM");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            c.setTime(d1);


            c.setTime(d);
            long time = c.getTimeInMillis();
            final String[] temimage = new String[1];
            DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("questions");
            Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("questionDate").equalTo(questiondateFormat.format(new Date(timeStampLong)));
            query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot userAnswerSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        temimage[0] = userAnswerSnapshot.getRef().getKey();
                        sessionManager.addImageName(temimage[0]);
                        Log.e("", "on image" + temimage[0]); //the tenimage value is not getting transferred.

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }

        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    databaseReference.child("time").child("timestamp").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
}
```

This function is getting the work done but not sending the value on the first launch resulting in app crash.

The crash gives java's null pointer exception. All the places where the value
 is being transferred is null.

Edit: I tried to log the values and check whether the listener is being called in the very first app launch but it never reached the log. So that was a problem So it switched the intent inside the listener rather than using a timer of 4 second so that whenever the listener get the value the activity changes but then the app never switched from the very first splash activity.

Comment: Is there a crash log you can share?

Comment: the crash is always the null pointer exception of the value i am sharing using shared preferences. @Tigger

Comment: The common Android / Google way to do things is in the background as much as possible. I'm guessing on the initial run Firebase has simply not finished registering the device / App combo yet so therefore your request will return `null`. One option would be to use an `AsyncTask` that checks for `null`, waits, tries again until the result is not `null` with a message on the splash screen that you are doing some initial run stuff - so the user knows this is a once off delay.

Comment: Hey, I tried that but the activity isn't changing. That is the listener does not get the value the first timel̥ @Tigger